# How to create a layout with layered components while having rounded corners?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I want to achieve the following design in Android, any idea how I can do that?

Basically it is:

- a container with 2 top rounded corners
- first layer: the image of a    map
- second layer: a semi transparent header

[image: Desired design]

Comment: use frame layout for layers. and for corners use shape drawable.

Comment: You can create an image for semi transparent header and use frame layout  or try layer list

Comment: I actually did something like that but the "top layer" does not retain the rounded corners.